# Sorting and range compression for internal references

Tags: cross-referencing, sorting

Both [cite](https://ctan.org/pkg/cite) and [amsrefs](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs) offer sorting and range compression, so that I can carelessly cite a list of references that resolves to, say, [3, 5, 1, 4] and leave those packages to produce [1, 3–5].

Is there any package that provides a direct interface to this sort of functionality, without assuming that I want to use it for a bibliography?  Specifically, I want to reference an enumerated list, and to be able to use not `\cites{citation3,citation5,citation1,citation4}` but `\refs{reference3,reference5,reference1,reference4}`.  I understand that there can be complications—what if some reference labels are hierarchical, like 5.2, or non-numeric, like A?—so a description of the limitations or requirements of any such package is also welcome.

(I should clarify that, though my specific application is to referencing, I would prefer a lightweight package that *doesn't* force a complete re-working of my references.  Thus, although, for example, [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) can do what I want, it's rather heavyweight.  I would prefer something that *just* offers the sorting and range compression, and leaves me to take care of the rest.)

Comment: Not heavyweight in the sense that my computer can't handle it, but heavyweight in the sense that it can interact badly with other packages and, e.g., might not be accepted in a journal paper.  Similarly, when working with coauthors, it's best if the package I use does not require them to change their authoring practices.

Comment: (The previous [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604300/sorting-and-range-compression-for-internal-references#comment1515386_604300) was in response to a now-deleted comment pointing out that [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) is not really heavyweight from a computational point of view.)